# Don't auto bump question here on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, community-user, bump

As most of us already know, questions that do not have accepted or upvoted answers (aka Unanswered questions) are being bumped to the front page by "dummy edit" made by the system account after some time, two months here on Meta.

It's good feature on the main Stack Overflow website, allowing fresh eyes to see the question and offer new insight, that even if will be too late for the OP can help other people with the same problem. Once such insight is upvoted, the question will rest peacefully down the stack.

**However**, here on Meta things are different, at least from my point on view. Questions here are often about change that just happened or user asking for instant support - in the future it won't be relevant anymore. Same with discussions: I don't see much point bringing old discussions back to the front, from what I see they exhaust themselves within few days maximum a week.

So in my opinion the auto bump feature can be turned off here on Meta - unless you think there's good reason to have it?

Comment: So it is in your theory valid to close all meta questions older than half a year as *Too localized*?

Comment: @Chichiray - absolutely not. All I'm saying is let those questions rest and don't bring them back to the front page automatically. If someone manually dig them up and post new answer it's totally legit.

Comment: Just add a vote to one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It brings new eyes to old feature requests. I don't see what's the harm.

Comment: Took me some time to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: ... except this only holds for things that are actually tagged [tag:feature-request]. This is a terrible answer, and I'm not sure why @ShadowWizard accepted it.

Comment: @E.P. I disagree. It also applies to bug reports. Discussions also can use some fresh eyes. Really can't see what's so terrible about the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, if you think five-year old status-norepro [tag:bug]s by long-vanished OPs need fresh eyes, then I think we should agree to disagree. Ditto for some five-year-old resolved discussion on some long-closed question with a single answer at -3. Community bumping on meta is a bad idea, but at the very least it needs to stop being indiscriminate bumping.

Comment: @E.P. obviously I meant bugs not yet fixed, we got enough of these... all in all, over the years I got to believe the benefit of the auto bumping is bigger than the harm. So we do get occasional useless bump, really no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

I understand you, but I'm not sure how disabling this is useful. There are not many of them anyway. If you encounter one of which you're sure that it shouldn't be resurrected, just spend your close vote or flag of the day.

Comment: It's useful to not litter the front page with non relevant questions. I'm against closing them and as far as I know, even moderator can't move a question back down the stack.

Comment: If they are not eligible to close, then they may be still relevant to others.

Comment: Some questions yes, but here on Meta there are many questions that won't be relevant after some time. Examples: bug that was fixed. Discussing recent change to UI. Feature request that was handled already.